# Complex MySQL join with dynamic where

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

Here are my two tables that I'm trying to join...

```
    name: notifications
-------------------------------------------
content | position | member  | contentType
-------------------------------------------
test a  | manager  | testera | Email
test b  | manager  | testera | Email
test c  | manager  | testera | SMS
-------------------------------------------

    name: position
-----------------------------------------------
position  |  member  |  getsEmail  |  getsSMS
-----------------------------------------------
manager   |  testera |  1          |  0
employee  |  testerb |  0          |  1
-----------------------------------------------
```

I would like to return the rows from the "notifications" table where the member is "testera", and the contentType from the "position" table is equal to "1".  So for the above table data, I want to get the first two rows from "notifications" returned since the contentType of "Email" is allowed in the position table.

Is this possible to do with my table structure?

Comment: Just curious, does everyone in the position table get EITHER email OR SMS. Do some get neither (0-0)? Are some 'allowed to get' both (1-1)?

Comment: Can contentType ever be anything other than Email or SMS - for example, could it be NULL?

Comment: Everyone in the notifications table can only have a contentType of "Email" or "SMS". Never NULL. In the position table, there can be any combination of on or off for getsEmail and getsSMS (0-0, 0-1, 1-1, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select n.*
from notifications n
join position p 
  on n.member = p.member and
     case n.contentType when 'Email' then p.getsEmail 
                        when 'SMS' then p.getsSMS end = 1
where n.member = 'testera'
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7dc7/16).

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for. I had been playing around with the case statement, but was trying to figure it out in the where clause instead of on the join. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
SELECT n.* 
  FROM notifications n
  JOIN position p
    ON n.member = p.member
 WHERE (n.contentType = 'Email' AND p.getsEmail = 1)
    OR (n.contentType = 'SMS' AND p.getsSMS = 1)
```

Result:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ CONTENT ║ POSITION ║ MEMBER  ║ CONTENTTYPE ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║ test a  ║ manager  ║ testera ║ Email       ║
║ test b  ║ manager  ║ testera ║ Email       ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7dc7/15)

#### [SQLFiddle with more data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b545/4)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can define the contenttype is email or sms

```
$contenttype="Email";
$query="select * from notification,position where position.member='testera' and position.gets".$contenttype."='1' ";
```